# Абстрактный класс ABC

Tags: python, python-3.6

Что делает метод `register` ?

```
class Foo:
    pass


class Abstract(ABC):
    pass

Abstract.register(Foo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) написано:

> `register(subclass)` Register subclass as a “virtual subclass” of this ABC.

В переводе на русский:

> Регистрирует подкласс как “виртуальный подкласс” этого ABC.

```
from abc import ABC

class MyABC(ABC):
    pass

MyABC.register(tuple)

assert issubclass(tuple, MyABC)
assert isinstance((), MyABC)
```

Comment: Как это виртуальный?

Comment: @Андрей это значит, что он будет восприниматься инерпретатором как наследник класса, хотя на самом деле таковым не является.